# GPX Parser for Java?

Tags: java, parsing, api, gpx

Are there any Java libraries for parsing GPX files? I need to parse many GPX files into our own data structure (our own database).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research, there is really no Java API/Lib for parsing GPX files, but I found a nice approach for parsing it using [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/)

Using this Tutorial: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html

Steps:
 1. Download GPX 1.0 and 1.1 Schema file (xsd)
 2. Generate Java File from it using [Eclipse Plugin](https://jaxb-workshop.dev.java.net/plugins/eclipse/xjc-plugin.html)
 3. Init JAXBContext with package name of generated GPX java files (mine was "topografix.gpx.schema10")
 4. Parse GPX File

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("topografix.gpx.schema10");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Gpx root = (Gpx) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("sample.gpx"));
List<Trk> tracks = root.getTrk();
....
```

Comment: Eclipse plugin: broken link :( http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaxb-builder/ perhaps?

Comment: This is a good place to start off faster: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ip0T91q70PA

Answer (score 10):

This question is too old and so do the answers.
Thanks to the open source world, we have now [jgpx, on google code](http://code.google.com/p/jgpx/) ([forked multiple times on github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=jgpx)) and [GPXParser, on sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpxparser/?source=navbar). There are also a lot of results for [a search on Github](https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=gpx&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

I'm not sure which one is more mature (one of them is marked as Alpha) but you can try them and let us know here.

#### Edit

Have a look at [processing-gpx](https://github.com/RandomEtc/processing-gpx), it seems promising.

Here is a quick example

```
import tomc.gpx.*;

// outside setup()
GPX gpx;

  // inside setup()
  gpx = new GPX(this);

  // when you want to load data
  gpx.parse("test.gpx"); // or a URL

  // inside draw()
  for (int i = 0; i < gpx.getTrackCount(); i++) {
    GPXTrack trk = gpx.getTrack(i);
    // do something with trk.name
    for (int j = 0; j < trk.size(); j++) {
      GPXTrackSeg trkseg = trk.getTrackSeg(j);
      for (int k = 0; k < trkseg.size(); k++) {
        GPXPoint pt = trkseg.getPoint(k);
        // do something with pt.lat or pt.lon
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < gpx.getWayPointCount(); i++) {
    GPXWayPoint wpt = gpx.getWayPoint(i);
    // do something with wpt.lat or wpt.lon or wpt.name or wpt.type
  }
```

Comment: It is tied to the Android OS.

Answer (score 3):

Very nice.  However, I needed to do:

```
    GpxType gpx = null;
    try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(PACKAGE_NAME);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<GpxType> root = (JAXBElement<GpxType>)unmarshaller
            .unmarshal(new File(TEST_FILE));
        gpx = root.getValue();
    } catch(JAXBException ex) {
       // TODO
    }

    List<TrkType> tracks = gpx.getTrk();
    for(TrkType track : tracks) {
        System.out.println(track.getName());
    }
```

BTW I used http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1.

-Ken

Comment: yes I know, for simplicity I left out try-catch block and for Production code you have to support both 1.0 and 1.1 (so your and mine code combined). What I did was first try to unmarshall using schema10, if it throws an exception, i tried using schema11 (for 1.1). If that fails again that file is not a supported GPX file.

Answer (score 3):

Ready to use, open source, and fully functional java GpxParser (and much more) here
https://sourceforge.net/projects/geokarambola/

Details here
https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/110606810455751902142

With the above library parsing a GPX file is a one liner:

```
Gpx gpx = GpxFileIo.parseIn( "SomeGeoCollection.gpx" ) ;
```

Getting its points, routes or tracks trivial too:

```
ArrayList<Route> routes = gpx.getRoutes( ) ;
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Would be nice to have it on github and/or as maven repository

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any library specialized in parsing GPX files, but since GPX is XML you can use your preferred Java XML parser for reading it.
The GPX format is documented here (includes XSD schema):
http://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp

Comment: since GPX is very wide spread, I thought there should be some lib/api for that. Because I didn't want to start from scratch especially if someone should have already done that.